# Ruby on Rails - Multiple values for form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and I'm looking to make a simple page that allows a user to list their computer skills.

I need fields to be dynamically created by clicking 'Add another skill.' I've found some JS that can do this, but I'm having trouble getting the multiple fields stored in a single database entry in Rails.

Any ideas?

--

For example:

*Skills*

-MS Office

-Mac OS X

-AutoCad

-StackOverflow

**Add Another Skill**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to add an entry in a new table for each skill, instead of a single database entry.

Steps involved in this:

1. You would have a table called 'Skills' that would have a primary id and text field for the text.
2. Add in a `has_many :skills` to your 'User' object.
3. In the form, each added item would have the name something like: `user[skills][]`.  This will add create skill objects when posted to the server.

If you need to keep with a single database entry you could YAML to serialize and de-serialize an array of skills (not tested much).

```
require 'yaml'

def update

   user.skills = ["MS Office", "Mac OS X"].to_yaml

end
```

And in the template:

```
<% YAML::load(user.skills).each do |s| %>
   <%= s %>
<% end %>
```